# ListView builder consuming more spaces than necessary in Autocomplete widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I was looking for a simple textField with suggestion option widget. Found this Sample code from [api.flutter.dev](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RawAutocomplete-class.html). I followed it and for some reason, the ListView builder keeps leaving large amount of space at the beginning of the list build.

Switching to RawAutoComplete doesn't work. Switching it into ListView gives the same result. Flutter inspector just skip the section.

Here's my code:

```
class First extends StatefulWidget {
  const First({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FirstState createState() => _FirstState();
}

class _FirstState extends State<First> {
  List<String> rise = ["rise","rose","petal","dandelion"];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: _first(),
    );
  }
  _first(){
    return Center(
      child: Autocomplete<String>(
        optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textController) {
          if (textController.text == '') {
            return rise;
          }
          return rise.where((String option) {
            return option.contains(textController.text.toLowerCase());
          });
        },
        optionsViewBuilder: (BuildContext context,
            AutocompleteOnSelected<String> onSelected,
            Iterable<String> options) {
          return Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Material(
              elevation: 4.0,
              child: Container(
                width: 400,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                 itemCount: rise.length,
                 itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index){
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        onSelected(rise[index]);
                      },
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(rise[index]),
                      ),
                    );
                 },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        onSelected: (string) {},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the picture

[image]

Here's the "Show guideline" option of the inspector

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html

*By default, ListView will automatically pad the list's scrollable extremities to avoid partial obstructions indicated by MediaQuery's padding. To avoid this behavior, override with a zero padding property.*

So, you can remove top padding of ListView.

```
...
MediaQuery.removePadding(
        context: context,
        removeTop: true,
        child: ListView(
...
```

Comment: Thank you. Though, may I ask why does this specific case of Listview would have padding on the top?

Comment: I updated the reason to body of top padding at ListView.